# Remote Desktop Connection for Mac not being able to connect?

Tags: remote-desktop

I have the latest version of Remote Desktop Connection client form Mac (2.1.1), the one that is also included in Office 2011 but I am not able to connect to the Windows machine.

I checked the logs on the Windows machine and found nothing.

It keeps asking me for user/password/domain... and I am entering them properly.

FYI, the computer is on domain.

Comment: Tried with CoRD and I got an interesting error "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by leaving the domain, joining it back and rebooting the machine (Windows).